# Message sent by Microsoft Teams bot is not displayed in the conversation

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have tried to send MS Teams bot message request via rest api:

End point: [https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ca/apis/v3/conversations/{conversation](https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ca/apis/v3/conversations/%7Bconversation) id}/activities

{"text":"test","type":"message"}

And got empty response:
{}

The message i sent did not appear in the conversation.
Any idea where i could have misconfigured?

It is possible that trustServiceUrl needs to be run before a message is sent, i can't find equivalent rest api to call.

Comment: put a debug point on the method where the post method (when you message is sent) is handled. Check are you getting any values in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do need call trustServiceUrl before sending the message. In addition, you need to have additional properties on your activity, like the destination user or tenant id. Please refer to the documents on this, and good starting places are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet).